# Algebra with Logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve:

$$-1.4= \log\left(\frac{x}{0.3}\right)$$

I've been out of school for 20 years and cannot remember order of operations of basic algebra!  please help!

Comment: When I hit INV Log on the calculator, I get:

Comment: Sorry-   0.0398=(x/.3),

Comment: Ah!  Thank you!  I actually got that answer with my 0.0398 from above, but you re-taught me something about exponents with your more elegant solution.  Thank you guru of Math!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Raise each side of the equation by a power of the base of your log (probably $2$ or $10$)...

---

You know what? Since you've been out of school for 20 years, I'll just cut you some slack and give you the full solution:

- $-1.4=\log_{2}\dfrac{x}{0.3} \implies 2^{-1.4}=\dfrac{x}{0.3} \implies 2^{-1.4}\cdot0.3=x \implies x\approx0.11367$
- $-1.4=\log_{10}\dfrac{x}{0.3} \implies 10^{-1.4}=\dfrac{x}{0.3} \implies 10^{-1.4}\cdot0.3=x \implies x\approx0.01194$

Comment: I think the same, if he is out of school probably the hint is not going to work

Comment: @rlartiga: Yeah, thought so... Anyways, not sure whether or not I'm gonna keep this answer, due to the "minor achievement" gained here...

Comment: Hey! You never know how it's going to help, and I might progress to calculus one eon!  I'm a 41 year old woman going back to school.  It's good for the brain.  I can't believe your resume Barak- you are like an alien.  Good for you and thanks again!

Comment: @Nevadavista: You're welcome... While you're at it, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

$$-1.4=\log_a{\frac{x}{0.3}}$$
Where $a$ is the base of the logarithm then by the definition of logarithm this is equivalent to:

$$a^{-1.4}=\frac{x}{0.3}$$
$$x=0.3a^{-1.4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$-1.4= \log(x/.3)$$
$$-14/10= \log(x/(3/10)$$
$$10^{-14/10}=x/(3/10)$$
$$10^{7/5}=10x/3$$
$$3\cdot10^{7/5}=10x$$
$$x=(3/10)\cdot10^{7/5}$$
$$x=3\cdot10^{7/5-1}$$
$$x=3\cdot10^{2/5}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$ \log x=\log_{10} x $$
$$ \log\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\log x -\log y $$
$$ 10^{\log x}=x $$
So
$$ -1.4= \log\left(\frac{x}{0.3}\right)= \log x -\log 0.3 $$
$$ -1.4+\log 0.3= \log x $$
$$ 10^{-1.4+\log 0.3}=10^{\log x}=x $$
$$ x=10^{-1.4}\cdot 10^{\log 0.3}=0.3\cdot 10^{-1.4} $$
$$ x=0.0119432151166\dots $$